# DuckDuckGo returns 418 when requesting with Python

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm writing a script that opens firefox with the first duckduckgo result it finds for a given term.
I know. Its very useful.

But when copying a url from my browser and requesting it with python:

```
url = "https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=python+request+duckduckgo&ia=software"
req = r.get(url)
```

Duckduckgo returns a 418.

What is happening? 
Does duckduckgo recognize that I'm doing automated requests and decides to turn into a teapot?
And if so, how can I avoid it?

Also I know there's a duckduckgo api for python but I'm doing this project to get started with `requests` and `beautifulsoup`.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/62674787/5320906

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is 418 "I'm a teapot" really an HTTP response code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52340027/is-418-im-a-teapot-really-an-http-response-code)

Comment: @RoshinRaphel not really. I'm more interested in how I can avoid it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a 'user-agent' header, even one as simple as:

```
req = r.get(url, headers={'user-agent': 'my-app/0.0.1'})
```

**Update: complete code with reasonably named variables**

```
import requests

url = "https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=python+request+duckduckgo&ia=software"
response = requests.get(url, headers={'user-agent': 'my-app/0.0.1'})
response.raise_for_status() # throw an exception if not a 200 return code
# or test response.status_code if you do not want to throw an exception
data = response.text # this is the HTML assuming that is what the URL returns
print(data)
```

Prints:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en_US" class="no-js has-zcm  no-theme "><head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><title>python request duckduckgo at DuckDuckGo</title><link rel="stylesheet" href="/s1909.css" type="text/css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="/r1909.css" type="text/css"><meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow"><meta name="referrer" content="origin"><meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="python request duckduckgo"><link rel="preconnect" href="https://links.duckduckgo.com"><link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" /><link id="icon60" rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/assets/icons/meta/DDG-iOS-icon_60x60.png?v=2"/><link id="icon76" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/assets/icons/meta/DDG-iOS-icon_76x76.png?v=2"/><link id="icon120" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/assets/icons/meta/DDG-iOS-icon_120x120.png?v=2"/><link id="icon152" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/assets/icons/meta/DDG-iOS-icon_152x152.png?v=2"/><link rel="image_src" href="/assets/icons/meta/DDG-icon_256x256.png"/><script type="text/javascript">var ct,fd,fq,it,iqa,iqm,iqs,iqp,iqq,qw,dl,ra,rv,rad,r1hc,r1c,r2c,r3c,rfq,rq,rds,rs,rt,rl,y,y1,ti,tig,iqd,locale,settings_js_version='s2475.js',is_twitter='',rpl=1;fq=0;fd=1;it=0;iqa=0;iqbi=0;iqm=0;iqs=0;iqp=0;iqq=0;qw=3;dl='en';ct='US';iqd=0;r1hc=0;r1c=0;r3c=0;rq='python%20request%20duckduckgo';rqd="python request duckduckgo";rfq=0;rt='';ra='ffab';rv='';rad='';rds=30;rs=0;spice_version='2000';spice_paths='{}';locale='en_US';settings_url_params={};rl='us-en';rlo=0;df='';ds='';sfq='';iar='';vqd='3-149609696422854606330346289888770817762-151254838983446808561626137548835915940';safe_ddg=0;show_covid=0;</script><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" /><meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true" /><meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="no" /></head><body class="body--serp"><input id="state_hidden" name="state_hidden" type="text" size="1"><span class="hide">Ignore this box please.</span><div id="spacing_hidden_wrapper"><div id="spacing_hidden"></div></div><script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/l118.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/locale/en_US/duckduckgo14.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/util/u469.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/d2827.js"></script><div class="site-wrapper  js-site-wrapper"><div class="welcome-wrap js-welcome-wrap"></div><div id="header_wrapper" class="header-wrap js-header-wrap"><div id="header" class="header  cw"><div class="header__search-wrap"><a tabindex="-1" href="/?t=ffab" class="header__logo-wrap js-header-logo"><span class="header__logo js-logo-ddg">DuckDuckGo</span></a><div class="header__content  header__search"><form id="search_form" class="search--adv  search--header  js-search-form" name="x" action="/"><input type="text" name="q" tabindex="1" autocomplete="off" id="search_form_input" class="search__input search__input--adv js-search-input" value="python request duckduckgo"><input id="search_form_input_clear" class="search__clear  js-search-clear" type="button" tabindex="3" value="X"/><input id="search_button" class="search__button  js-search-button" type="submit" tabindex="2" value="S" /><a id="search_dropdown" class="search__dropdown" href="javascript:;" tabindex="4"></a><div id="search_elements_hidden" class="search__hidden  js-search-hidden"></div></form></div></div><div id="duckbar" class="zcm-wrap  zcm-wrap--header  is-noscript-hidden"></div></div><div class="header--aside js-header-aside"></div></div><div id="zero_click_wrapper" class="zci-wrap"></div><div id="vertical_wrapper" class="verticals"></div><div id="web_content_wrapper" class="content-wrap "><div class="serp__top-right  js-serp-top-right"></div><div class="serp__bottom-right  js-serp-bottom-right"><div class="js-feedback-btn-wrap"></div></div><div class="cw"><div id="links_wrapper" class="serp__results js-serp-results"><div class="results--main"><div class="search-filters-wrap"><div class="js-search-filters search-filters"></div></div><noscript><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=/html?q=python%20request%20duckduckgo"><link href="/css/noscript.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"><div class="msg msg--noscript"><p class="msg-title--noscript">You are being redirected to the non-JavaScript site.</p>Click <a href="/html/?q=python%20request%20duckduckgo">here</a> if it doesn't happen automatically.</div></noscript><div id="message" class="results--message"></div><div class="ia-modules js-ia-modules"></div><div id="ads" class="results--ads results--ads--main is-invisible js-results-ads"></div><div id="links" class="results is-invisible js-results"></div></div><div class="results--sidebar js-results-sidebar"><div class="sidebar-modules js-sidebar-modules"></div><div class="is-invisible js-sidebar-ads"></div></div></div></div></div><div id="bottom_spacing2"> </div></div><script type="text/javascript"></script><script type="text/JavaScript">function nrji() {nrj('/t.js?q=python%20request%20duckduckgo&l=us-en&s=0&dl=en&ct=US&ss_mkt=us&p_ent=&ex=-1');nrj('/d.js?q=python%20request%20duckduckgo&l=us-en&s=0&a=ffab&dl=en&ct=US&ss_mkt=us&vqd=3-149609696422854606330346289888770817762-151254838983446808561626137548835915940&p_ent=&ex=-1&sp=1');;};DDG.ready(nrji, 1);</script><script src="/g2379.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">DDG.page = new DDG.Pages.SERP({ showSafeSearch: 0, instantAnswerAds: false });</script><div id="z2"> </div><div id="z"></div></body></html>
```

You have to understand that the HTML may contain JavaScript that executes after the page is loaded which modifies the page content. So what you see visibly in a browser may not correspond to what you see in HTML loaded via `requests`. If that is the case you probably need a different tool such as `selenium` to drive an actual web browser.

Comment: hmm. the response turns to 200. The html is not really what I get in the browser though...

Comment: I don't understand your comment. I was showing you how to avoid an error response and to get a normal completion response. I have updated my answer to show you the code that must follow.

Comment: Ok I'll try to explain: the response is correct. But when I'm looping through the links with BeautifulSoup there are only 3(```/?t=ffab ,
javascript:; ,
/html/?q=python%20request%20duckduckgo
```)

Answer (score 3):

While this might not be an exact issue, duckduckgo is definitely not for bots and scraping its search content. Take a look at their [robots.txt file](https://duckduckgo.com/robots.txt). This file from websites tells you how to treat their website for crawlers vs users – what pages are allowed to be crawled and which ones can't be crawled.

From the looks of it, all of what you're trying to crawl is `Disallowed`. There's a chance you're getting teapot as a response because that is their response to crawlers without permission.

If you're trying to learn about `requests`, it might be better to avoid search engines. Most of the common ones that I know of disallow outside crawlers.

Answer (score 0):

I would have added this on to my existing answer by I would have exceeded the maximum character length. In a a way it is a second answer related to my first answer wherein I stated that the HTML returned by `requests` may not reflect what you visibly see in a browser because of JavaScript code that is loaded and executed, which modified the page contents. In that case you need to resort to using a tool such as `selenium`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=python+request+duckduckgo&ia=software")
time.sleep(3) # give page a chance to fully load
print(driver.page_source)
driver.quit()
```

And the output:

```
<html lang="en_US" class="has-zcm   js no-touch opacity csstransforms3d csstransitions svg cssfilters is-not-mobile-device full-urls has-footer"><head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><title>python request duckduckgo at DuckDuckGo</title><link rel="stylesheet" href="/s1909.css" type="text/css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="/r1909.css" type="text/css"><meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow"><meta name="referrer" content="origin"><meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="python request duckduckgo"><link rel="preconnect" href="https://links.duckduckgo.com"><link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"><link id="icon60" rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/assets/icons/meta/DDG-iOS-icon_60x60.png?v=2"><link id="icon76" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/assets/icons/meta/DDG-iOS-icon_76x76.png?v=2"><link id="icon120" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/assets/icons/meta/DDG-iOS-icon_120x120.png?v=2"><link id="icon152" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/assets/icons/meta/DDG-iOS-icon_152x152.png?v=2"><link rel="image_src" href="/assets/icons/meta/DDG-icon_256x256.png"><script type="text/javascript" src="s2475.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" async="" src="/a.js?p=1&amp;q=python%20request%20duckduckgo&amp;from=nlp_longtail"></script><script type="text/javascript" async="" src="/d.js?q=python%20request%20duckduckgo&amp;l=us-en&amp;s=0&amp;a=ffab&amp;dl=en&amp;ct=US&amp;ss_mkt=us&amp;vqd=3-149609696422854606330346289888770817762-334759569224655846812843926827516956510&amp;p_ent=&amp;ex=-1&amp;sp=1&amp;v7exp=a&amp;sltexp=b&amp;wiadrk=b"></script><script type="text/javascript" async="" src="/t.js?q=python%20request%20duckduckgo&amp;l=us-en&amp;s=0&amp;dl=en&amp;ct=US&amp;ss_mkt=us&amp;p_ent=&amp;ex=-1&amp;v7exp=a&amp;sltexp=b&amp;wiadrk=b"></script><script type="text/javascript">var ct,fd,fq,it,iqa,iqm,iqs,iqp,iqq,qw,dl,ra,rv,rad,r1hc,r1c,r2c,r3c,rfq,rq,rds,rs,rt,rl,y,y1,ti,tig,iqd,locale,settings_js_version=\'s2475.js\',is_twitter=\'\',rpl=1;fq=0;fd=1;it=0;iqa=0;iqbi=0;iqm=0;iqs=0;iqp=0;iqq=0;qw=3;dl=\'en\';ct=\'US\';iqd=0;r1hc=0;r1c=0;r3c=0;rq=\'python%20request%20duckduckgo\';rqd="python request duckduckgo";rfq=0;rt=\'\';ra=\'ffab\';rv=\'\';rad=\'\';rds=30;rs=0;spice_version=\'2000\';spice_paths=\'{}\';locale=\'en_US\';settings_url_params={};rl=\'us-en\';rlo=0;df=\'\';ds=\'\';sfq=\'\';iar=\'\';vqd=\'3-149609696422854606330346289888770817762-334759569224655846812843926827516956510\';safe_ddg=0;show_covid=0;</script><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true"><meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="no"><link title="DuckDuckGo" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" rel="search" href="https://duckduckgo.com/opensearch.xml?atb=v231-2__"></head><body class="body--serp"><input id="state_hidden" name="state_hidden" type="text" size="1"><span class="hide">Ignore this box please.</span><div id="spacing_hidden_wrapper"><div id="spacing_hidden"></div></div><script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/l118.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/locale/en_US/duckduckgo14.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/util/u469.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/d2827.js"></script><div class="site-wrapper  js-site-wrapper" style="min-height: 928px;"><div class="welcome-wrap js-welcome-wrap"></div><div id="header_wrapper" class="header-wrap js-header-wrap"><div id="header" class="header  cw"><div class="header__search-wrap"><a tabindex="-1" href="/?t=ffab" class="header__logo-wrap js-header-logo"><span class="header__logo js-logo-ddg">DuckDuckGo</span></a><div class="header__content  header__search"><form id="search_form" class="search--adv  search--header  js-search-form has-text" name="x" action="/" method="GET"><input type="text" name="q" tabindex="1" autocomplete="off" id="search_form_input" class="search__input--adv js-search-input" value="python request duckduckgo" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off"><input id="search_form_input_clear" class="search__clear  js-search-clear" type="button" tabindex="3" value="X"><input id="search_button" class="search__button  js-search-button" type="submit" tabindex="2" value="S"><a id="search_dropdown" class="search__dropdown" href="javascript:;" tabindex="4"></a><div id="search_elements_hidden" class="search__hidden  js-search-hidden"><input type="hidden" class="js-search-hidden-field" name="t" value="ffab"></div><div class="search__autocomplete"><div class="acp-wrap js-acp-wrap"></div><div class="acp-footer is-hidden js-acp-footer"><span class="acp-footer__instructions">Shortcuts to other sites to search off DuckDuckGo</span><span class="acp-footer__link"><a class="no-visited js-acp-footer-link" href="/bang">Learn More</a></span></div></div></form></div></div><div id="duckbar" class="zcm-wrap  zcm-wrap--header  is-noscript-hidden"><div class="zcm"><ul class="zcm__menu zcm__constant has-zci" id="duckbar_static"><li class="zcm__item"><a data-zci-link="web" class="zcm__link  js-zci-link  js-zci-link--web " href="#">All</a></li><li class="zcm__item"><a data-zci-link="images" class="zcm__link  js-zci-link  js-zci-link--images " href="#">Images</a></li><li class="zcm__item"><a data-zci-link="videos" class="zcm__link  js-zci-link  js-zci-link--videos " href="#">Videos</a></li><li class="zcm__item"><a data-zci-link="news" class="zcm__link  js-zci-link  js-zci-link--news " href="#">News</a></li><li class="zcm__item"><a data-zci-link="maps_expanded" class="zcm__link  js-zci-link  js-zci-link--maps_expanded " href="#">Maps</a></li></ul><ul class="zcm__menu zcm__dynamic" id="duckbar_new"><span id="duckbar_dynamic_sep" class="zcm__sep--h sep--before is-hidden"></span></ul><ul class="zcm__menu zcm__dropdowns js-duckbar-dropdowns" id="duckbar_dropdowns"><span class="zcm__sep--h sep--before is-hidden js-duckbar-dropdowns-separator"></span><li class="zcm__item"><div class="dropdown dropdown--settings"><a class="zcm__link dropdown__button js-dropdown-button">Settings</a></div></li></ul></div></div></div><div class="header--aside js-header-aside"><a class="header__button--menu  js-side-menu-open" href="#">⇶</a><div class="header--aside__item showcase header__label"><span class="header__clickable js-hl-button" data-type="showcase"><span class="js-popout-trig" aria-haspopup="true" aria-label="Check out the list of things that we\'ve also made." role="button" aria-pressed="false"><span id="wedonttrack">Privacy, simplified.</span></span><span class="popout-trig  js-popout"><span class="js-popout-link js-showcase-popout ddgsi ddgsi-down" aria-hidden="true" data-type="showcase"></span><div class="modal modal--popout modal--popout--bottom-left modal--popout--sm  js-popout-main" data-type="showcase"><div class="modal__box"><div class="modal__body"><nav aria-labelledby="wedonttrack"><section class="showcase__dropdown-top"><ul aria-label="Here are some things that we made that you might like."><li class="fix showcase__dropdown__list"><a href="/app" class="eighteen js-hl-item" aria-hidden="true" data-type="showcase" data-id="app"><div class="woman-icon"></div></a><a href="/app" class="text-left showcase__link eighty js-hl-item" data-type="showcase" data-id="app"><h1 class="showcase__heading">Get Our App &amp; Extension</h1><p class="showcase__subheading">Protect your data on every device.</p></a></li><li class="fix showcase__dropdown__list"><a href="/newsletter" class="eighteen js-hl-item" aria-hidden="true" data-type="showcase" data-id="newsletter"><div class="mailbox-icon"></div></a><a href="/newsletter" class="text-left showcase__link eighty js-hl-item" data-type="showcase" data-id="newsletter"><h1 class="showcase__heading">Privacy in Your Inbox</h1><p class="showcase__subheading">Stay protected and informed with our privacy newsletters.</p></a></li><li class="fix showcase__dropdown__list"><a href="https://spreadprivacy.com/tag/device-privacy-tips/" class="eighteen js-hl-item" aria-hidden="true" data-type="showcase" data-id="blog"><div class="privacy-simplified-icon"></div></a><a href="https://spreadprivacy.com/tag/device-privacy-tips/" class="text-left showcase__link eighty js-hl-item" data-type="showcase" data-id="blog"><h1 class="showcase__heading">Protect Your Devices</h1><p class="showcase__subheading">Check out our privacy device guides.</p></a></li><li class="fix showcase__dropdown__list"><a href="https://duckduckgo.com/spread" class="eighteen js-hl-item" aria-hidden="true" data-type="showcase" data-id="spread"><div class="spread-icon"></div></a><a href="https://duckduckgo.com/spread" class="text-left showcase__link eighty js-hl-item" data-type="showcase" data-id="spread"><h1 class="showcase__heading">Spread DuckDuckGo</h1><p class="showcase__subheading">Help your friends and family join the Duck Side!</p></a></li></ul></section><section class="showcase__dropdown-bottom"><ul class="text-left" aria-label="We\'ve got even more things for you."><li class="fix showcase__dropdown__list"><a href="https://duckduckgo.com/donations" class="eighteen showcase__icon js-hl-item" aria-hidden="true" data-type="showcase" data-id="donations"><div class="donations-icon"></div></a><a href="https://duckduckgo.com/donations" class="text-left showcase__link eighty showcase__text js-hl-item" data-type="showcase" data-id="donations">$1,900,000 in privacy donations!</a></li><li class="fix showcase__dropdown__list"><a href="https://duckduckgo.com/traffic" class="eighteen showcase__icon js-hl-item" aria-hidden="true" data-type="showcase" data-id="traffic"><div class="traffic-icon"></div></a><a href="https://duckduckgo.com/traffic" class="text-left showcase__link eighty showcase__text js-hl-item" data-type="showcase" data-id="traffic">Over 51 Billion anonymous searches.</a></li><li class="fix showcase__dropdown__list"><a href="https://donttrack.us/" class="eighteen showcase__icon js-hl-item" aria-hidden="true" data-type="showcase" data-id="dnt"><div class="privacy-tips-icon"></div></a><a href="https://donttrack.us/" class="text-left showcase__link eighty showcase__text js-hl-item" data-type="showcase" data-id="dnt">Learn why reducing tracking is important.</a></li></ul></section></nav></div></div></div></span></span></div><div class="header--aside__item header--aside__social header__label social"><span class="header__clickable js-hl-button" data-type="social"><span class="js-popout-trig header--aside__social-icon " aria-haspopup="true" aria-label="Keep in touch" role="button" aria-pressed="false"><span class="ddgsi ddgsi-horn" data-type="social"></span></span><span class="popout-trig js-popout"><span class="js-popout-link ddgsi ddgsi-down" aria-hidden="true" data-type="social"></span><div class="modal modal--popout modal--popout--bottom-left modal--popout--sm  js-popout-main" data-type="social"><div class="modal__box"><div class="modal__body"><div class="social__link"><a href="https://twitter.com/duckduckgo" class="js-hl-item social__link__text" data-type="social" data-id="twitter"><img class="social__icon js-lazysvg" data-src="/assets/icons/header/twitter.svg"><span>Twitter</span></a></div><div class="social__link"><a href="https://reddit.com/r/duckduckgo" class="js-hl-item social__link__text" data-type="social" data-id="reddit"><img class="social__icon js-lazysvg" data-src="/assets/icons/header/reddit.svg"><span>Reddit</span></a></div><div class="social__link"><a href="https://spreadprivacy.com" class="js-hl-item social__link__text" data-type="social" data-id="blog"><img class="social__icon js-lazysvg" data-src="/assets/icons/header/blog.svg"><span>Blog</span></a></div><div class="social__link"><a href="https://duckduckgo.com/newsletter" class="js-hl-item social__link__text" data-type="social" data-id="newsletter"><img class="social__icon js-lazysvg" data-src="/assets/icons/header/newsletter.svg"><span>Newsletter</span></a></div></div></div></div></span></span></div></div></div><div id="zero_click_wrapper" class="zci-wrap"></div><div id="vertical_wrapper" class="verticals"></div><div id="web_content_wrapper" class="content-wrap "><div class="serp__top-right  js-serp-top-right"></div><div class="serp__bottom-right  js-serp-bottom-right"><div class="js-feedback-btn-wrap"><div class="btn feedback-btn"><a href="#" class="feedback-btn__send js-feedback-start">Send feedback</a><div class="feedback-btn__icon-wrap is-hidden js-feedback-icon-wrap"><a href="#" class="feedback-btn__icon ddgsi feedback-btn__icon--love js-feedback-love"></a><a href="#" class="feedback-btn__icon ddgsi feedback-btn__icon--nolove js-feedback-nolove"></a></div></div></div></div><div class="cw"><div id="links_wrapper" class="serp__results js-serp-results"><div class="results--main"><div class="search-filters-wrap"><div class="js-search-filters search-filters"><div class="dropdown dropdown--region "><a class="dropdown__button dropdown__button js-dropdown-button">All Regions</a></div><div class="dropdown  dropdown--safe-search "><a href="#" class="dropdown__button js-dropdown-button">Safe Search: Moderate</a></div><div class="dropdown  dropdown--date "><a href="#" class="dropdown__button js-dropdown-button">Any Time</a></div></div></div><noscript><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=/html?q=python%20request%20duckduckgo"><link href="/css/noscript.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"><div class="msg msg--noscript"><p class="msg-title--noscript">You are being redirected to the non-JavaScript site.</p>Click <a href="/html/?q=python%20request%20duckduckgo">here</a> if it doesn\'t happen automatically.</div></noscript><div id="message" class="results--message"></div><div class="ia-modules js-ia-modules"></div><div id="ads" class="results--ads results--ads--main js-results-ads"></div><div id="links" class="results js-results"><div id="r1-0" class="result results_links_deep highlight_d result--url-above-snippet" data-domain="pypi.org" data-hostname="pypi.org" data-nir="1"><div class="result__body links_main links_deep"><h2 class="result__title"><a class="result__a" rel="noopener" href="https://pypi.org/project/DuckDuckGo-Python3-Library/"><b>DuckDuckGo</b>-Python3-Library · PyPI</a><a rel="noopener" class="result__check" href="https://pypi.org/project/DuckDuckGo-Python3-Library/"><span class="result__check__tt">Your browser indicates if you\'ve visited this link</span></a></h2><div class="result__extras js-result-extras"><div class="result__extras__url"><span class="result__icon "><a href="/?q=python%20request%20duckduckgo+site:pypi.org&amp;t=ffab" title="Search domain pypi.org/project/DuckDuckGo-Python3-Library/" class="js-result-extras-site_search"><img data-src="//external-content.duckduckgo.com/ip3/pypi.org.ico" height="16" width="16" title="Search domain pypi.org/project/DuckDuckGo-Python3-Library/" class="result__icon__img js-lazyload-icons" src="//external-content.duckduckgo.com/ip3/pypi.org.ico"></a></span><a href="https://pypi.org/project/DuckDuckGo-Python3-Library/" rel="noopener" class="result__url js-result-extras-url"><span class="result__url__domain">https://pypi.org</span><span class="result__url__full">/project/DuckDuckGo-Python3-Library/</span></a></div></div><div class="result__snippet js-result-snippet">Files for <b>DuckDuckGo</b>-Python3-Library, version 1.0; Filename, size File type <b>Python</b> version Upload date Hashes; Filename, size <b>DuckDuckGo</b> Python3 Library-1..tar.gz (2.0 kB) File type Source <b>Python</b> version None Upload date Dec 22, 2016 Hashes View</div></div></div><div id="organic-module"></div><div id="r1-1" class="result results_links_deep highlight_d result--url-above-snippet" data-domain="stackoverflow.com" data-hostname="stackoverflow.com" data-nir="1"><div class="result__body links_main links_deep"><h2 class="result__title"><a class="result__a" rel="noopener" href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63058873/duckduckgo-returns-418-when-requesting-with-python"><b>Duckduckgo</b> returns 418 when requesting with <b>Python</b> - Stack ...</a><a rel="noopener" class="result__check" href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63058873/duckduckgo-returns-418-when-requesting-with-python"><span class="result__check__tt">Your browser indicates if you\'ve visited this link</span></a></h2><div class="result__extras js-result-extras"><div class="result__extras__url"><span class="result__icon "><a href="/?q=python%20request%20duckduckgo+site:stackoverflow.com&amp;t=ffab" title="Search domain stackoverflow.com/questions/63058873/duckduckgo-returns-418-when-requesting-with-python" class="js-result-extras-site_search"><img data-src="//external-content.duckduckgo.com/ip3/stackoverflow.com.ico" height="16" width="16" title="Search domain stackoverflow.com/questions/63058873/duckduckgo-returns-418-when-requesting-with-python" class="result__icon__img js-lazyload-icons" src="//external-content.duckduckgo.com/ip3/stackoverflow.com.ico"></a></span><a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63058873/duckduckgo-returns-418-when-requesting-with-python" rel="noopener" class="result__url js-result-extras-url"><span class="result__url__domain">https://stackoverflow.com</span><span class="result__url__full">/questions/63058873/duckduckgo-returns-418-when-requesting-with-python</span></a></div></div><div class="result__snippet js-result-snippet">I\'m writing a script that opens firefox with the first <b>duckduckgo</b> result it finds for a given term. I know. Its very useful. But when copying a url from my browser and requesting it with <b>python</b>: ur...</div></div></div><div id="r1-2" class="result results_links_deep highlight_d result--url-above-snippet" data-domain="github.com" data-hostname="github.com" data-nir="1"><div class="result__body links_main links_deep"><h2 class="result__title"><a class="result__a" rel="noopener" href="https://github.com/crazedpsyc/python-duckduckgo/">GitHub - crazedpsyc/<b>python</b>-<b>duckduckgo</b>: A library for ...</a><a rel="noopener" class="result__check" href="https://github.com/crazedpsyc/python-duckduckgo/"><span class="result__check__tt">Your browser indicates if you\'ve visited this link</span></a></h2><div class="result__extras js-result-extras"><div class="result__extras__url"><span class="result__icon "><a href="/?q=python%20request%20duckduckgo+site:github.com&amp;t=ffab" title="Search domain github.com/crazedpsyc/python-duckduckgo/" class="js-result-extras-site_search"><img data-src="//external-content.duckduckgo.com/ip3/github.com.ico" height="16" width="16" title="Search domain github.com/crazedpsyc/python-duckduckgo/" class="result__icon__img js-lazyload-icons" src="//external-content.duckduckgo.com/ip3/github.com.ico"></a></span><a href="https://github.com/crazedpsyc/python-duckduckgo/" rel="noopener" class="result__url js-result-extras-url"><span class="result__url__domain">https://github.com</span><span class="result__url__full">/crazedpsyc/python-duckduckgo/</span></a></div></div><div class="result__snippet js-result-snippet">A library for querying the <b>DuckDuckGo</b> API. Contribute to crazedpsyc/<b>python</b>-<b>duckduckgo</b> development by creating an account on GitHub.</div></div></div><div id="r1-3" class="result results_links_deep highlight_d result--url-above-snippet" data-domain="github.com" data-hostname="github.com" data-nir="1"><div class="result__body links_main links_deep"><h2 class="result__title"><a class="result__a" rel="noopener" href="https://github.com/mikejs/python-duckduckgo">GitHub - mikejs/<b>python</b>-<b>duckduckgo</b>: A library for querying ...</a><a rel="noopener" class="result__check" href="https://github.com/mikejs/python-duckduckgo"><span class="result__check__tt">Your browser indicates if you\'ve visited this link</span></a></h2><div class="result__extras js-result-extras"><div class="result__extras__url"><span class="result__icon "><a href="/?q=python%20request%20duckduckgo+site:github.com&amp;t=ffab" title="Search domain github.com/mikejs/python-duckduckgo" class="js-result-extras-site_search"><img data-src="//external-content.duckduckgo.com/ip3/github.com.ico" height="16" width="16" title="Search domain github.com/mikejs/python-duckduckgo" class="result__icon__img js-lazyload-icons" src="//external-content.duckduckgo.com/ip3/github.com.ico"></a></span><a href="https://github.com/mikejs/python-duckduckgo" rel="noopener" class="result__url js-result-extras-url"><span class="result__url__domain">https://github.com</span><span class="result__url__full">/mikejs/python-duckduckgo</span></a></div></div><div class="result__snippet js-result-snippet">A library for querying the Duck Duck Go API. Contribute to mikejs/<b>python</b>-<b>duckduckgo</b> development by creating an account on GitHub.</div></div></div><div id="r1-4" class="result results_links_deep highlight_d result--url-above-snippet" data-domain="pypi.org" data-hostname="pypi.org" data-nir="1"><div class="result__body links_main links_deep"><h2 class="result__title"><a class="result__a" rel="noopener" href="https://pypi.org/project/requests-custom/"><b>requests</b>-custom · PyPI</a><a rel="noopener" class="result__check" href="https://pypi.org/project/requests-custom/"><span class="result__check__tt">Your browser indicates if you\'ve visited this link</span></a></h2><div class="result__extras js-result-extras"><div class="result__extras__url"><span class="result__icon "><a href="/?q=python%20request%20duckduckgo+site:pypi.org&amp;t=ffab" title="Search domain pypi.org/project/requests-custom/" class="js-result-extras-site_search"><img data-src="//external-content.duckduckgo.com/ip3/pypi.org.ico" height="16" width="16" title="Search domain pypi.org/project/requests-custom/" class="result__icon__img js-lazyload-icons" src="//external-content.duckduckgo.com/ip3/pypi.org.ico"></a></span><a href="https://pypi.org/project/requests-custom/" rel="noopener" class="result__url js-result-extras-url"><span class="result__url__domain">https://pypi.org</span><span class="result__url__full">/project/requests-custom/</span></a></div></div><div class="result__snippet js-result-snippet"><b>Python\'s</b> <b>requests</b> with custom configuration. Package to work with custom <b>requests</b> capabilities. Current capabilities available:</div></div></div><div id="r1-5" class="result results_links_deep highlight_d result--url-above-snippet" data-domain="www.blog.pythonlibrary.org" data-hostname="www.blog.pythonlibrary.org" data-nir="1"><div class="result__body links_main links_deep"><h2 class="result__title"><a class="result__a" rel="noopener" href="https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/06/08/python-101-how-to-submit-a-web-form/"><b>Python</b> 101: How to submit a web form - The Mouse Vs. The ...</a><a rel="noopener" class="result__check" href="https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/06/08/python-101-how-to-submit-a-web-form/"><span class="result__check__tt">Your browser indicates if you\'ve visited this link</span></a></h2><div class="result__extras js-result-extras"><div class="result__extras__url"><span class="result__icon "><a href="/?q=python%20request%20duckduckgo+site:www.blog.pythonlibrary.org&amp;t=ffab" title="Search domain www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/06/08/python-101-how-to-submit-a-web-form/" class="js-result-extras-site_search"><img data-src="//external-content.duckduckgo.com/ip3/www.blog.pythonlibrary.org.ico" height="16" width="16" title="Search domain www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/06/08/python-101-how-to-submit-a-web-form/" class="result__icon__img js-lazyload-icons" src="//external-content.duckduckgo.com/ip3/www.blog.pythonlibrary.org.ico"></a></span><a href="https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/06/08/python-101-how-to-submit-a-web-form/" rel="noopener" class="result__url js-result-extras-url"><span class="result__url__domain">https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org</span><span class="result__url__full">/2012/06/08/python-101-how-to-submit-a-web-form/</span></a></div></div><div class="result__snippet js-result-snippet">Today we\'ll spend some time looking at three different ways to make <b>Python</b> submit a web form. In this case, we will be doing a web search with <b>duckduckgo</b>.com searching on the term "<b>python</b>" and saving the result as an HTML file. We will use <b>Python\'s</b> included urllib modules and two 3rd party packages: <b>requests</b> and mechanize.We have three small scripts to cover, so let\'s get cracking!</div></div></div><div id="r1-6" class="result results_links_deep highlight_d result--url-above-snippet" data-domain="pypi.org" data-hostname="pypi.org" data-nir="1"><div class="result__body links_main links_deep"><h2 class="result__title"><a class="result__a" rel="noopener" href="https://pypi.org/project/duckduckpy/">duckduckpy · PyPI - The <b>Python</b> Package Index</a><a rel="noopener" class="result__check" href="https://pypi.org/project/duckduckpy/"><span class="result__check__tt">Your browser indicates if you\'ve visited this link</span></a></h2><div class="result__extras js-result-extras"><div class="result__extras__url"><span class="result__icon "><a href="/?q=python%20request%20duckduckgo+site:pypi.org&amp;t=ffab" title="Search domain pypi.org/project/duckduckpy/" class="js-result-extras-site_search"><img data-src="//external-content.duckduckgo.com/ip3/pypi.org.ico" height="16" width="16" title="Search domain pypi.org/project/duckduckpy/" class="result__icon__img js-lazyload-icons"></a></span><a href="https://pypi.org/project/duckduckpy/" rel="noopener" class="result__url js-result-extras-url"><span class="result__url__domain">https://pypi.org</span><span class="result__url__full">/project/duckduckpy/</span></a></div></div><div class="result__snippet js-result-snippet">Features. Uses standard library only; Works on <b>Python</b> 2.6+ and 3.3+ Unit test coverage 100%; SSL and unicode support; Licensed under MIT license</div></div></div><div id="r1-7" class="result results_links_deep highlight_d result--url-above-snippet" data-domain="pypi.org" data-hostname="pypi.org" data-nir="1"><div class="result__body links_main links_deep"><h2 class="result__title"><a class="result__a" rel="noopener" href="https://pypi.org/project/duckduckgo2/">duckduckgo2 · PyPI - The <b>Python</b> Package Index</a><a rel="noopener" class="result__check" href="https://pypi.org/project/duckduckgo2/"><span class="result__check__tt">Your browser indicates if you\'ve visited this link</span></a></h2><div class="result__extras js-result-extras"><div class="result__extras__url"><span class="result__icon "><a href="/?q=python%20request%20duckduckgo+site:pypi.org&amp;t=ffab" title="Search domain pypi.org/project/duckduckgo2/" class="js-result-extras-site_search"><img data-src="//external-content.duckduckgo.com/ip3/pypi.org.ico" height="16" width="16" title="Search domain pypi.org/project/duckduckgo2/" class="result__icon__img js-lazyload-icons"></a></span><a href="https://pypi.org/project/duckduckgo2/" rel="noopener" class="result__url js-result-extras-url"><span class="result__url__domain">https://pypi.org</span><span class="result__url__full">/project/duckduckgo2/</span></a></div></div><div class="result__snippet js-result-snippet">Hashes for duckduckgo2-.242.tar.gz; Algorithm Hash digest; SHA256: 46ad296a518f183ae62d2d15459bcc69ca44a7614556f27f59dfc0db6599136a: Copy MD5</div></div></div><div id="r1-8" class="result results_links_deep highlight_d result--url-above-snippet" data-domain="duckduckgo.com" data-hostname="duckduckgo.com" data-nir="1"><div class="result__body links_main links_deep"><h2 class="result__title"><a class="result__a" rel="noopener" href="http://duckduckgo.com/"><b>DuckDuckGo</b></a><a rel="noopener" class="result__check" href="http://duckduckgo.com/"><span class="result__check__tt">Your browser indicates if you\'ve visited this link</span></a></h2><div class="result__extras js-result-extras"><div class="result__extras__url"><span class="result__icon "><a href="/?q=python%20request%20duckduckgo+site:duckduckgo.com&amp;t=ffab" title="Search domain duckduckgo.com" class="js-result-extras-site_search"><img data-src="//external-content.duckduckgo.com/ip3/duckduckgo.com.ico" height="16" width="16" title="Search domain duckduckgo.com" class="result__icon__img js-lazyload-icons"></a></span><a href="http://duckduckgo.com/" rel="noopener" class="result__url js-result-extras-url"><span class="result__url__domain">duckduckgo.com</span><span class="result__url__full"></span></a></div></div><div class="result__snippet js-result-snippet">The Internet privacy company that empowers you to seamlessly take control of your personal information online,    etc. (too long to post all of it)
```

You could, of course, use `driver.page_source` as input to Beautiful Soup.